# Deformity in the form of many, miniature leaves

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, citrus

I have a nulles clementine that isn't doing too great after a winter indoors, for a variety of different reasons that don't surprise me in the least. I am, however, at a loss to explain the new growth I'm seeing on it, which is coming up in the form of many (really) small leaves where there should only be one new one.

Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what sort of deficiency or disease would cause growth like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, it's not a disease. The tiny leaves will become branches and the larger leaves next to them will fall. This is something very common for plants that recover from a hard time.